# Set cursor position in edittext according to user click

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want the cursor to follow user click to edit existing text in the editText.
To disable action bar of editing in tablet i use:

```
 edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            }

            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

How to get cursor position according to user click in text ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Layout layout = ((EditText) v).getLayout();
float x = event.getX() + edittext.getScrollX();
int offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(0, x); 
edittext.setSelection(offset);
```

Comment: Please try to provide context with your answer.  A standalone answer may solve a problem in this specific scenario, but an explanation may solve many future problems.  Try to include what you think is causing the issue and why your answer will solve it.