# How to place cursor with click in text in EditText? (SOLVED)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-sdk-2.3

**Update:** ----->  SOLUTION

Since I asked this question I have read that if you disable the soft keyboard using the command `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);`, which I did, that it would disable the (blinking) cursor, which it does.

What I am doing is I created a keypad layout using Buttons and loading it as a fragment. (*Android doesn't seem to allow the alteration of the soft keyboard to serve ones needs.*) What I was wanting to do is re-enable the cursor so with a tap (click) the cursor could be positioned at the desired place in the String for editing.

EditText inherits from TextView, (*one wouldn't think this method would part of TextView*), which has a method called `setShowSoftInputOnFocus(bool);`. This method will disable the soft keyboard without disabling the cursor.

---

I am seeking to setup an EditText so a user can place the cursor at a desired random location in the EditText so part of the text can be modified. I would also like the cursor to be visible.

There is the Java code solution --> [Set cursor position in edittext according to user click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635243/set-cursor-position-in-edittext-according-to-user-click)

Isn't there XML attributes to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to define where the cursor should be setup, then you should do it programmatically as following:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setSelection(3); // Custom point Cursor
```

If you meant that user should be able to use the cursor, then simply set the cursor at the last as a good practice:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()); // End point Cursor
```

If you want to use XML and define this as a property, then you need to decide if this should be static or rather dependent on the user:

#### IF STATIC,  THEN USE THE FOLLOWING ATTRIBUTE

```
android.selection
```

#### IF NOT STATIC AND DEPENDS ON THE USER

In that case you will need to bind your **`XML layout file`** with the respective **`ViewController`**, which could be **`Activity`** or a **`Fragment`**, and setup a Int value which the layout file can read.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to set the `initial cursor position` through xml look at my answer**

Maybe create a custom EditText and reuse in any xml layout, customise it to do what you want:

**now in `res/values/attrs.xml`**

```
    <resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyCustomEditText">

      <attr name="cursor_position" format="string" />

    </declare-styleable>
    </resources>
```

**use custom edittext in xml layout**

```
<com.example.yourpackage.CustomEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:cursor_position="5" //it can be any index you want
      ..........
```

**custom edit text**

```
class CustomEditText extends EditText
 {
    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

          //get attribute of cursor_position
          TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCustomEditText, defStyle, 0);

          String index = a.getString(R.styleable.MyCustomEditText_cursor_position);
          //set the cursor index
          this.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(index));



    }
}
```