# Android customized keyboard the proper place of requesting focus?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-softkeyboard

I am working on a customized keyboard, the idea is user touch the `editText` then my keyboard is visible.

here is my code:

```
        inputEditText.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
           inputEditText.hideKeyboard()
           v.requestFocus()
           true
        }


inputEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
            inputEditTextKeyboard.visibility = if (hasFocus) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        }
```

everything works ok, but when you want to touch the middle of the text or long press to moving the cursor left or right it doesn't work.

Then I realized not using `setOnTouchListener` then it works fine:

```
inputEditText.accessibilityDelegate = object: View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
        override fun sendAccessibilityEvent(host: View, eventType: Int) {
            inputEditText.requestFocus()
            super.sendAccessibilityEvent(host, eventType)
        }
    }
```

But `View.AccessibilityDelegate()` would be called multiple times even though it works.

My question is am I on the right direction, where should the requestFocus should be called?

Comment: Text controller... I done this in my Notes App on Play Store... You have to use the text controller to place the position of the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as an example:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61377034/how-to-place-cursor-with-click-in-text-in-edittext-solved)

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setSelection(3);
```